# Complexity terminology

Tags: complexity-theory, runtime-analysis

What is the terminology used for speaking about complexity, when we don't study it asympotically (but exactly) ?

Thank you

Comment: "complexity".  (or "running time").

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen complexity studied in a non-asymptotic setting.

Comment: @RanG. for example, in the case of a "running time".

Comment: Concrete complexity.

Comment: I meant you can still use "complexity" when you talk about a specific instance. For instance, "what is the communication complexity of a specific algorithm instance? - 5Mbit". "What is the information complexity of this protocol that computes the AND function? - $\approx 1.4923$ bits"; "What is the running time of this function (on this specific input)? - 50nsec/1000cycles", etc.

Comment: exact complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common keyword that denotes this concept in contradistinction to asymptotic complexity is *concrete complexity*.